# How do I convert a controller http call to a Service/factory pattern that takes in a parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have a controller that is calling http.get, http.push and http.post methods.

I am learning angularjs and have found that it's best to call your http.get in your service file. I am able to do that with a simple http.get, but get confused with a http.get by id or http.get/http.post which takes a parameter:

My current controller looks like this

```
angular.module("app-complaints")
.controller("clcontrol", clcontrol);

function clcontrol($routeParams, $http, $scope) {
 $http.get(baseURL + "/api/complaints/" + $scope.complaintCase + "/checklists")
    .then(function (cl) {
        //success
        $scope.index = 0;
        $scope.cl = [];
        $scope.cl = cl;
}
```

I want to separate it out like this

controller.js

```
angular.module("app-complaints")
.controller('clcontrol', function ($http, $scope, $q, Service, $timeout) {
....
getCL();
function getCL(){
Service.getCl()
.success(function(cl){
$scope.cl = [];
$scope.cl = cl;
}
```

service.js

```
angular.module("app-complaints")
.factory('Service', ['$http', function ($http) {
        Service.getCL = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase + "/api/complaints/" + complaintCase + "/checklists")
    };

 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.  Make a factory that accepts parameters.

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", [ /* dependencies */]);

app.factory("SharedServices", ["$http", function($http) {
    return {
        getItems: function(url, parameters) {
            return $http.get(url, {
                //optional query string like {userId: user.id} -> ?userId=value
                params: parameters
            });
        },
        postItem: function(url, item) {
            var payload = {
                item: item
            };
            return $http.post(url, payload);
        },
        deleteItem: function(url, item) {
            var payload = {
                item: item
            };
            return $http({
                url: url,
                data: payload,
                method: 'DELETE',
            });
        }
        // ETC. ETC. ETC.
        // follow this pattern for methods like PUT, POST, anything you need
    };
}]);
```

**Use the service in your controller:**

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope","SharedServices", function($scope, SharedServices) {

    //do things with the shared service
    $scope.postMyThings = function() {
        SharedServices.postItems('path/to/api', itemsArray).then(function(response) {
            //success callback, do something with response.data
        }, function(response) {
            //an error has occurred
        });
    };

    $scope.getMyThing = function() {
        SharedServices.getItems('path/to/api/get').then(function(response) {
            //success callback, do something with response.data
        }, function(response) {
            //an error has occurred
        });
    }

}]);
```